# Store the directory address using filedialog.askdirectory() in tkinter, Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In a part of my code, I am going to get the directory of files from user. To do this there is an Open Button and Entry bar which shows the address like the picture below:

[image]

Open Button is bound to `filedialog.askdirectory()` and user could navigate through directories. The class below do this task:

```
class Open_File:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.file_path = ''
        self.open_button = tk.Button(master,
               text = 'Open',
               command = self.open_file)
        
        self.v = tk.StringVar(master)#, value = self.file_path)
        self.path_entry = tk.Entry(master, width=40, bg = 'white', textvariable=self.v)
        self.path_entry.xview_moveto(1)
        
        
    def open_file(self):
        self.file_path =filedialog.askdirectory()
        
        if self.file_path:  #check if file path is not None or empty
            self.v.set(self.file_path)  
            self.path_entry.xview_moveto(1)
            
    def return_path(self):
        return self.v.get()
```

Although the address displayed correctly in the Entry bar, I could not store it in a variable so I can use it in other parts of the code. For example, this code just returns an empty string for the address:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

open_file = Open_File(root)
open_button = open_file.open_button
path_entry = open_file.path_entry
slices_dir = open_file.return_path()

open_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
path_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)   



root.mainloop()
print(slices_dir)
```

I am on windows 10, my Python version is 3.8.3 (Anaconda), and the Tkinter version is 8.6

Answer (score 0):

try using Global variable, below simple example  :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd 

def callback():
    global name
    name= fd.askopenfilename() 
    print(name)
    
errmsg = 'Error!'
tk.Button(text='Click to Open File', 
       command=callback).pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.mainloop()
```